# My api is returning duplicate results, PHP

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have created an API in PHP so that every time it is called it returns a phone number that is in my MySQL database

When the phone number has been delivered or returned by the API, it is removed from the database, because it no longer interests me and I want to prevent it from being returned again.

The problem is when I make more than one request at the same time (at the same second), it returns the same phone number

What I tried to do was use `PDO::beginTransaction` to try to lock the table record (the phone number) so that another API request would not take that same number, but I have not succeeded, it still returns the same number phone

What happens is that at that same moment or second there can be more than 30 requests to the API requesting a phone number and it always returns the same number to (some) or all queries.
More than 60% of the queries return the same

The question is is there any way or method to fix this?

I attach my code so you can see what I tried:

```
try {
    $pdo->beginTransaction();

    $num_numbers = $pdo->prepare("SELECT count(*) as total FROM numbers WHERE user = :user  ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 1");
    $num_numbers->bindParam(':user', $user);
    if ($num_numbers->execute()) {
        $count = $num_numbers->fetchColumn();

        if ($count > 0) {

            $get_number = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM numbers WHERE user = :user ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1");
            $get_number->bindParam(':user', $user);
            if ($get_number->execute()) {

                $data = $get_number->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
                $id = $data['id'];
                $number = trim($data['number']);
                
                $update = $pdo->prepare("DELETE FROM numbers WHERE id = :id");
                $update->bindParam(':id', $id);
                if ($update->execute()) {
                    $pdo->commit();
                    echo json_encode(array("success" => "true", "number" => "$number",));
                }

            } else {
                echo json_encode(array("success" => "false"));
            }
        } else { 
            echo json_encode(array("success" => "false", "number" => "", "error" => "DB empty"));
        }
    } else {
        echo json_encode(array("success" => "false"));
    }
    
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
    $pdo->rollBack();
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zyR0X.png)

Comment: What do the calls to `$pdo->beginTransaction();` and `$pdo->commit();` return? If they fail, they will return `FALSE`.

Comment: why you're doing 2 select queries?